# Api Endpoints for Members and Administrators Users

Tags: api, asp.net-core-webapi, api-design

I have the following resources in an API:

Company > Project > ProjectUser > User

The resources are related as follows:

1. One company has many projects;
2. ProjectUser defines Users that can access a project;

I am defining the API endpoints to get projects:

```
"/projects" > Get all projects that authenticated user can access        

"/companies/{companyId}/projects" > Get projects with `companyId` that authenticated user can access
```

I need 3 more endpoints only accessible by users that are Administrators:

1. Get all projects of all users
2. Get all projects of user with a given `UserId`;
3. Get projects with `companyId` of user with a given `UserId`.

How should the 5 endpoints become?

Answer (score 0):

In situations such as this, user-specific resources are generally prefixed with something like `my`, `me`, `user`, etc. For example: `/my/projects` and `/my/companies/{companyId}/projects`. This helps distinguish between general requests that simply need authentication, but not resource-filtering, such as your admin case. For admin queries, you'd hit the `/projects` and `/companies/{companyId}/projects` endpoints. You can then protect these endpoints with something like `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` and assuming that the user is an admin, they'll receive all the projects. Whereas the `my` prefixed routes would simply require `[Authorize]` to ensure there's some authenticated user, and then would utilize resource-level authorization to return only projects belonging to that user.